# Can two FORTRAN modules use parts of one another?

Tags: module, fortran, circular-dependency

I know that circular dependence of modules in FORTRAN is forbidden.  But I am wondering how strong that proscription is.  Let's say I have:

```
module mod1
   integer, public :: i,j,k
   use mod2, only: m
end module mod1
```

and

```
module mod2
   integer, public :: l,m,n
   use mod1, only: j
end module mod2
```

It seems to me that this evades circularity in a logical sense, but that doesn't mean the standard allows it.  Should it work?

If so, I am having trouble compiling because, of course, mod1 wants to see mod2 and vice versa.  Is there a way around this?

Comment: *It seems to me that this evades circularity in a logical sense*; alas, not in a sense that the Fortran standard recognises.  The obvious (?) workaround is to move `m` and `j` into their own modules.

Comment: @HighPerformanceMark  Ok, then.  That's the way it is.  Thanks.

Comment: please really do use tag [tag:fortran] so that people can find your question. I have asked that multiple times. Fortran 90 is one old, even obsolete, version. Are you sure your question is limited to it? Even if yes, use tag fortran and add a version specific tag in addition.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

No, it shouldn't work. The standard says that a module must be "available" when a USE is seen. If mod2 hasn't been compiled by the time the "use mod2" is seen, the build will fail. (Some compilers might allow you to use a module defined later in the same source, some do not.) You might be able to use submodules (see https://software.intel.com/en-us/blogs/2015/07/07/doctor-fortran-in-we-all-live-in-a-yellow-submodule) to accomplish what you want - I don't know because clearly what you posted is not representative of your real application, but Mark's suggestion of a separate module is easier to understand.